# Determine error from Logcat - Android

Tags: android, logcat, illegalstateexception

Can anyone determine what is going wrong, or give me any clues? I think it is within the current activity (CreateProfileActivity), in this buttonClick method:

```
public void saveUserClick(View view){
        saveUserDetails();
        insertUserToDB();
        Log.d("yo", "yoyoyo");
        dbHelper.logDataBase();
    }
```

in particular, this line `dbHelper.logDataBase();`

Here is that methods declaration:

```
public void logDataBase(){
        // Getting all clothing items
        Log.d("Get database Items", "Getting all database items");

        List<ClothingItem> allClothingItems = this.getAllClothingItems();
        List<AppUser> allAppUsers = this.getAllAppUsers();
        for (ClothingItem clothingItem : allClothingItems) {
            Log.d("ClothingItem", clothingItem.getIdString());
        }
        for (AppUser appUser : allAppUsers) {
            Log.d("User", appUser.getImagePath());
        }
    }
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
12-30 02:39:57.499: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5474 objects / 286208 bytes in 138ms
    12-30 02:41:48.227: D/yo(277): yoyoyo
    12-30 02:41:48.227: D/Get database Items(277): Getting all database items
    12-30 02:41:48.227: E/dbHelper(277): SELECT  * FROM ClothingItem
    12-30 02:41:48.247: E/dbHelper(277): SELECT  * FROM AppUser
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 1
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 2
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 3
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 4
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 5
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 6
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 7
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 8
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 9
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 10
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 11
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/ClothingItem(277): 12
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/User(277): content://media/external/images/media/1
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/User(277): content://media/external/images/media/1
    12-30 02:41:48.247: D/AndroidRuntime(277): Shutting down VM
    12-30 02:41:48.247: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.btf271.fashionassistant.CreateProfileActivity.saveUserClick(CreateProfileActivity.java:50)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 11 more
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:122)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.btf271.dbhelper.dbhelper.logDataBase(dbhelper.java:138)
    12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 15 more
```

The VM appears to shut down after that logDatabase method for some reason. When i comment it out, it doesn't shut down.

Comment: can you put your dbHelper class source code and the code of where you initialize it.

Comment: try to comment out the Log.d calls in your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone determine what is going wrong, or give me any clues?

Yes. This first couple of lines tells us that it is in the `onClick`

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
```

its having trouble finishing that method (possibly due to an infinite loop in my experience).

These lines tell us that you are correct in that it is in the `onClick()` that you posted

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-30 02:41:48.267: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at    
com.btf271.fashionassistant.CreateProfileActivity.
saveUserClick(CreateProfileActivity.java:50)
```

and this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

tells you what the exception is. The next line that references your project

```
at com.btf271.dbhelper.dbhelper.logDataBase(dbhelper.java:138)
```

tells you that it is at line 138 of `dbhelper.java`

Comment: Thanks! Line 138 is `Log.d("User", appUser.getImagePath());` from logDatabase(). I commented it out and the exception doesn't occur. So NullPointerException on that line. There is no message. One of my AppUsers may not have an imagepath?

Comment: yep. `appUser` is `null` or possibly `getImagePath()` returns `null`. Set a breakpoint and see why it is `null`.

Comment: I probably clicked saveButton before entering the imagePath of the user a lot of times so some users have no imagePath. I need to do a lot of validation to stop this kind of thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you executing following line

```
dbHelper.logDataBase();
```

"dbHelper" reference is null. reason may be you didn't initialise it.