# having a lot of trouble setting up a listview using custom objects

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a class called Movies, which several properties such as rating/title/date. I query an api to return JSON data regarding these properties. My MAIN activity is a ui where I input a movie, click search, and it opens a new intent with the JSON data in a listview. I can get all the json data and read them from logs, but I cant view them from a listview. Here is how I start the intent..

```
try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ViewMovies.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("movielist", moviesList);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("intent", "failed");
                }
```

moviesList is an ArrayList which definitely has recorded data in it(I verified by printing them to console). It has lets say over 20 things..My ViewMovies class which is extending listview keeps crashing as soon as the intent starts, I see a null pointer exception, but not sure where.

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ViewMovies extends ListActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        Bundle a = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Movies> m = a.getParcelableArrayList("movielist");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Movies>(ViewMovies.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m));

    }
}
```

I am reading and learning a lot but can't get over this hurdle. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I have tried overriding ArrayAdapter but again I had no idea what I was doing, I just copied other people's but here it is if it helps

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movies> {

    private ArrayList<Movies> movies;

    public MyClassAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Movies> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.movies = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        // assign view we are converting to a local var
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        /*
         * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this
         * method. The variable simply refers to the position of the current
         * object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter iterates through the list we
         * sent it)
         * 
         * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
         */
        Movies i = movies.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
            // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

            TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieId);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
            TextView vote_avg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieAvg);
            TextView backdrop_path = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieBackdrop);
            TextView release_date = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieRelease);
            TextView original_title = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieTitle2);
            TextView vote_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieCount);
            TextView adult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieAdult);
            TextView poster = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.moviePoster);
            TextView popularity = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.moviePopularity);

            // check to see if each individual textview is null.
            // if not, assign some text!
            id.setText(i.getId());
            title.setText(i.getTitle());
            vote_avg.setText(i.getVote_average());
            backdrop_path.setText(i.getBackdrop_path());
            release_date.setText(i.getRelease_date());
            original_title.setText(i.getOriginal_title());
            vote_count.setText(i.getVote_count());
            adult.setText(i.isAdult());
            poster.setText(i.getPoster_path());
            popularity.setText(i.getPopularity());
        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return v;

    }
}
```

If I remove the custom array adapter and instead use a string adapter with test strings, then the listview works, but the point is I need to view a list of movies in my listview, not strings. My movie class overrode toString() which I thought was the answer but no change. Here is my movies class

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Movies implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private int vote_average;
    private String backdrop_path;
    private String release_date;
    private String original_title;
    private int vote_count;
    private String adult;
    private String poster_path;
    private int popularity;

    public Movies(int id, String title, int vote_average, String backdrop_path,
            String release_date, String original_title, int vote_count,
            String adult, String poster_path, int popularity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.original_title = original_title;
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
        this.adult = adult;
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    private Movies(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.vote_average = in.readInt();
        this.backdrop_path = in.readString();
        this.release_date = in.readString();
        this.original_title = in.readString();
        this.vote_count = in.readInt();
        this.adult = in.readString();
        this.poster_path = in.readString();
        this.popularity = in.readInt();
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movies [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", vote_average="
                + vote_average + ", backdrop_path=" + backdrop_path
                + ", release_date=" + release_date + ", original_title="
                + original_title + ", vote_count=" + vote_count + ", adult="
                + adult + ", poster_path=" + poster_path + ", popularity="
                + popularity + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getVote_average() {
        return vote_average;
    }

    public void setVote_average(int vote_average) {
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
    }

    public String getBackdrop_path() {
        return backdrop_path;
    }

    public void setBackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public String getOriginal_title() {
        return original_title;
    }

    public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }

    public int getVote_count() {
        return vote_count;
    }

    public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
    }

    public String isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(String adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public int getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(int popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeInt(this.vote_average);
        dest.writeString(this.backdrop_path);
        dest.writeString(this.release_date);
        dest.writeString(this.original_title);
        dest.writeInt(this.vote_count);
        dest.writeString(this.adult);
        dest.writeString(this.poster_path);
        dest.writeInt(this.popularity);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movies>() {
        public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movies(in);
        }

        public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movies[size];
        }
    };
}
```

error:

```
01-02 14:37:52.283: D/AndroidRuntime(2273): Shutting down VM
01-02 14:37:52.283: W/dalvikvm(2273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jdmb/com.example.jdmb.ViewMovies}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:291)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:454)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.example.jdmb.ViewMovies.onCreate(ViewMovies.java:20)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     ... 11 more
```

UPDATE: so it turns out I was starting the intent at the wrong spot, once I moved it out the intent started delivering the data correctly. I can see the listview now its just horribly formatted, will spend time figuring out how to make it look nice.

Comment: Post the logcat so we can help you find *where* the `NPE` is occurring. There's way too much code here for us to guess without the logcat.

Comment: I can't find a way to copy and paste it but basically it says NPE @ .ViewMovies. I believe it could mean my movies list is empty but it should not be. I verified before sending the data that it was indeed full, and receiving it should populate it. I read I don't need to override arrayadapter when using objects is this right? as long as I override toString()

Comment: If using Eclipse, there is a save icon that allows you to save to a file. You can copy/paste from there or just highlight all the lines and copy/paste here

Comment: And **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832688/determine-error-from-logcat-android/20832743#20832743)** will tell you how to read it to know exactly which line is causing the exception.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and check that movie list was received correctly? I suspect a problem with parcel able implementation.

Comment: I tried printing the movies once the intent loaded but it crashes before I can try anything, EDITED op for erro log

Comment: Yes you are giving the adapter a null reference for your list. Something is wrong with parcelable implementation

Comment: It is happening in your `getCount()` method.  Please post the method from the ArrayAdapters (MyClassAdapter) class.  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 14:37:52.293: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:291)`

Comment: hmm isn't MyClassAdapater the class you are asking for?

Comment: I already posted, getCount is in the base adapter not his code. It is NPE because he is giving the adapter a null list.

Comment: oh alright, ill start to look at where that could be happening, its not null before sending, I should have mentioned I copied the Parcelable code too so I would not know if that part is incorrect yet

Comment: You're right, I was half reading the code so I missed the fact it is an ArrayAdapter instead of a genericAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<Movies> m = a.getParcelableArrayList("movielist");
 Log.d("m is null" + (m == null ? "yes" : "no");
```

I think that your array list isn't retrieved correctly because getCount of ArrayAdapter is the statement causing the NULL - Pointer Exception.
Your class Movies doesn't contain a default (non - parameterized, trivial) constructor which also can cause problems when working with Lists.
The "ViewMovies.this" isn't correct imho, you should just use "this".

Comment: You guys were right, it said it is null...not sure what to do from here but i'll be back after I try some things